# access android emulated file system debug flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I know similar questions have been asked before, but none of the answers seem to apply to my situation.

I am attempting to read a file through my flutter and using a emulator. Not my phone.

When i attempt to read a file it tells me that the it cant find the path to me file:

FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app_name/files/bootsrap/tree_.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

so my question is this: where is the path '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app_name/files/' physically located on my harddrive?

I have gone to to android-studio and right clicked on my virtual devices and select 'show on disk' but dont think that is the location it is looking for my file on disk.

I need to have my app load a config.json file but i dont know where to place this file on my disk so that it can read it while running my emulator.

in my app i am using `getExternalStorageDirectory();`

to get the location in my app.

Comment: This is not a location of internal app directory for your app. App path starts with `data/data`, not `storage/emulated`. Try to open File Explorer in Android Studio and manually find a path to an app.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this is where i am confused. Where is File Explorer in Android studios? I am not using android studios i am using vscode? I read online i need to go to view->tools window -> device explorer.... but i dont see this? Do i need to create a android studios project? I was thinking the correct place to go would be through AVD manager, but i dont see file explorer there...?

Comment: File Explorer available only in Android Studio. You can try debug your app and request different paths and detect only exists.

Comment: `so my question is this: where is the path '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app_name/files/' physically located on my harddrive?` That path resides on your emulator. The same path would be used on a real Android device. It is no path on your development pc at all.

Comment: @fartem `This is not a location of internal app directory for your app. ` Its a very valid app specific directory on every emulator or device.